# Simple_one_for_one can only be terminated if appointed SHUTDOWN strategy to brutal_kill?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

The supervisor is an OTP behavior.

```
init([]) ->
    RoomSpec = {mod_zytm_room, {mod_zytm_room, start_link, []},
                transient, brutal_kill, worker, [mod_zytm_room]},
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 10, 10000}, [RoomSpec]}}.
```

Above code will invoke child's `terminate` method.

But if I change the `brutal_kill` to an integer timeout (e.g. 6000), the `terminate` method was never invoked.

I see an explanation in the Erlang document:

> The dynamically created child processes of a simple-one-for-one
>   supervisor are not explicitly killed, regardless of shutdown strategy,
>   but are expected to terminate when the supervisor does (that is, when
>   an exit signal from the parent process is received).

But I cannot fully understand. Is it said that `exit(Pid, kill)` can terminate a `simple_one_for_one` child spec while `exit(Pid, shutdown)` can't ?

===================================update====================================

mod_zytm_room_sup.erl

```
-module(mod_zytm_room_sup).

-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/0, init/1, open_room/1, close_room/1]).

start_link() -> 
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    RoomSpec = {mod_zytm_room, {mod_zytm_room, start_link, []},
                transient, brutal_kill, worker, [mod_zytm_room]},
    {ok, {{simple_one_for_one, 10, 10000}, [RoomSpec]}}.

open_room(RoomId) ->
    supervisor:start_child(?MODULE, [RoomId]).

close_room(RoomPid) ->
    supervisor:terminate_child(?MODULE, RoomPid).
```

mod_zytm_room.erl

```
-module(mod_zytm_room).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/1]).

-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, handle_call/3, code_change/3, terminate/2]).

start_link(RoomId) ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [RoomId], []).

init([RoomId]) ->
    {ok, []}.

terminate(_, _) ->
    error_logger:info_msg("~p terminated:~p", [?MODULE, self()]),
    ok.

...other methods ommited.
```

mod_zytm_sup.erl

```
-module(mod_zytm_sup).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-export([start_link/0]).

-export([init/1, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, handle_call/3, code_change/3, terminate/2]).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link(?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, []}.

%% invoked by an erlang:send_after event.
handle_info({'CLOSE_ROOM', RoomPid}, State) ->
    mod_zytm_room_sup:close_room(RoomPid),
    {noreply, State}.

...other methods ommited.
```

Both `mod_zytm_sup` and `mod_zytm_room_sup` are a part of a system supervision tree, `mod_zytm_sup` invoke `mod_zytm_room_sup` to create or close mod_zytm_room process.

Comment: could you add your code for the terminate function for the child process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I've got wrong result.

To make it clear:

1. `brutal_kill` strategy **kill** child process immediately.
2. The `terminate` method will be invoked if the simple_one_for_one's shutdown strategy is an integer timeout. The child must declare `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` in its `init` callback.

FYI, Manual on Erlang doc:

> If the gen_server is part of a supervision tree and is ordered by its
>   supervisor to terminate, this function will be called with
>   Reason=shutdown if the following conditions apply:
>
> the gen_server has been set to trap exit signals, and the shutdown
>   strategy as defined in the supervisor's child specification is an
>   integer timeout value, not brutal_kill.

Comment: **NOTE** The `terminate` callback is not expected to actually terminate the child. It is meant to do any necessary clean-up after the server and when it returns the behaviour itself will end the process. And do any logging etc that has been specified.

Answer (score 1):

> The dynamically created child processes of a simple-one-for-one
>   supervisor are not explicitly killed, regardless of shutdown strategy,
>   but are expected to terminate when the supervisor does (that is, when
>   an exit signal from the parent process is received).

Note that this is no longer true.  Since Erlang/OTP R15A, dynamic children [are explicitly terminated](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/47759479146ca11ad81eca0bb3236b265e20601d) as per the shutdown strategy.